# Else syntax error when nesting array formula

Tags: awk

I am recieving a syntax error on "else" for this shell:

```
{for (i=8;i<=NF;i+=3)
        {if ($0~"=>") # if-else statement designed to flag file / directory transfers 
            print "=> flag,"$1"," $2","$3","$4 ","$5","$6","$7"," $(i)","$(i+1)","$(i+2);
                {split ($(i+2), array, "/");
                    for (x in array) 
                        {j++; 
                        a[j] =j; 
                        printf (array[x] ",");} 
                        printf ("%s\n", "");}
        else
            print "no => flag,"$1"," $2","$3","$4 ","$5","$6","$7"," $(i)","$(i+1)","$(i+2)
        }
}
```

Can't figure out why. If I delete the array block (starting with split()), all is well. But I need to scan the contents of $(i+2), so cutting it does me no good.

Also, if anyone has guidance on a good list of how to interpret error messages, that would be great.

Thanks for your advice.

---

EDIT: here is the above script laid out with sensible formatting:

```
{
    for (i=8;i<=NF;i+=3) {
        if ($0~"=>") # if-else statement designed to flag file / directory transfers
            print "=> flag,"$1"," $2","$3","$4 ","$5","$6","$7"," $(i)","$(i+1)","$(i+2);
        {
            split ($(i+2), array, "/");
            for (x in array) {
                j++;
                a[j] =j;
                printf (array[x] ",");
            }
            printf ("%s\n", "");
        }
        else
            print "no => flag,"$1"," $2","$3","$4 ","$5","$6","$7"," $(i)","$(i+1)","$(i+2)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks more like an awk script than shell. Also, what is the exact error message you get?

Comment: That's not a shell, it's part of an awk script, nothing at all to do with any shell. If you structure your code more legibly it'd be far easier to spot errors. I just did that for you and IMHO it's obvious at a glance now where the problems are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first, since you didn't post any samples of input and expected output so didn't test it at all. Could you please try following, I hope you are running this in `.awk` script style. Also these are mostly syntax/cosmetic changes NOT on logic part, since no background was given on problem.

```
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
{
  for (i=8;i<=NF;i+=3){
    if ($0~/=>/){
       print "=> flag,"$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$(i),$(i+1),$(i+2)
       split ($(i+2), array, "/");
       for(x in array){ 
         j++; 
         a[j] =j; 
         printf (array[x] ",")
       } 
       printf ("%s\n", "")
     }
     else{
       print "no => flag",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$(i),$(i+1),$(i+2)
     }
   }
}
```

***Problems fixed in OP's attempt:***

- `{` starting curly braces(which indicates that if condition of for loop with multiple statements is started) could be in last of the line where they are present, NOT in next line, for better visibility purposes, I fixed in `for` loop and `if` condition first.
- Since you are using regexp matching with a pattern so I fixed from `$0~"=>"` TO `$0~/=>/`.
- Added `BEGIN` section in your attempt where I have set `OFS`(output field separator) value to `,` so that you need NOT to print like `","` to print comma between variables, just `,` between variables will do the trick.
- Fixed indentation, so that we are NOT confused where to close loop/condition and where to NOT.